# Why is the EmbeddedFileProvider not hierarchical?

Tags: asp.net-core

Today, I was attempting to use the [`EmbeddedFileProvider`](https://github.com/aspnet/FileSystem/blob/1.0.0-beta4/src/Microsoft.AspNet.FileProviders/EmbeddedFileProvider.cs) as a read-only fake for an `IFileProvider`. Unfortunately, getting "directory" contents proved impossible because of the following lines of code:

```
// Non-hierarchal.
if (!subpath.Equals(string.Empty))
{
    return new NotFoundDirectoryContents();
}
```

Given that embedded files (at least, with beta 4) retain their folder structure using `/`'s and a new `EmbeddedFileProvider` can at least list the contents that way, I find this a bit surprising.

While it is easy enough to implement my own `HierarchicalEmbeddedFileProvider`, what is the design decision to make the framework version non-hierarchical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest version of DNX we made a change so that embedded files and resources do not retain their path: `/` gets replaced by `.`. The hierarchy is flattened to names that are valid C# full type names. It is the same thing that MSBuild did before.

Since `.` can also appear in the file name, it is not possible to know the hierarchy.

Comment: I can understand but it should have been an option.